# Angular5 - active class not added on page reload using routerlinkactive directive

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-directives

app.routing.ts

{ path:'dashboard/:name', component:DashboardComponent}

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" routerLink="/dashboard/{{selectedPlatform}}"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true" ></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
```

For navigation, active class added properly for the route "/dashboard/cps", but when i reload the page active class not added.This issue comes only for the dynamic values. Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Thanks in advance